# PHPmyAdmin and sorting a database table

Tags: php, sql, sorting, search-engine, forum

[edit]: I'm terribly sorry for my timing on asking this question.  I've just discovered that you can use the command

```
"ORDER BY `table`.`table_col` DESC"
```

to order your results from a MySQL table.

I am working on creating forum and I am using ajax to get results from a database table.
I would like to order these results before I display them on the page, sorted by a timestamp of the current day of the month.

the day for each post is a two digit number in my MySQL table i.e. `06` for post one, `09` for post two, `21` for post 3

I know how to write the script to sort these, but I would like to know if there is an easier way.

Can I simply set the table in my phpMyAdmin to keep each post sorted in order from least to greatest on the value of the day column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes and Keys have an order, and *often* selecting from a table gives results in the order of the index/key relevant to the query.

That, however, is not always the case.

In SQL, no matter what you do to the table, the result set *can* come out in a completely different order.

For that reason, the ***only*** way to guarantee the order of the results is to specify an `ORDER BY` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the "order by"-clause  in your select statement?

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.